# How to display the confirmed friends

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named user_join:

```
| join_to_id | join_by_id | approved |
```

> `join_to_id` means to whom user sending the request
>
> `join_by_id` means who is sending request
>
> `approved` means request accepted or not, if accepted value will be 'Yes' else value will be 'No'

Now I want to display the names of those users who APPROVED BY current id user or who APPROVED CURRENT id user.

Here is my code :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_join where (join_to_id = '".$_GET['id']."' and approved = 'Yes' and join_by_id != '".$_GET['id']."' ) 
          or (join_by_id = '".$_GET['id']."' and approved = 'Yes' and join_to_id != '".$_GET['id']."') ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: You need help, but your question also might need some sample data to illustrate the relationships which your table is storing.  Can you include some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking much too complicated. This should do it:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM user_join 
 WHERE '".$_GET['id']."' IN (join_to_id, join_by_id) 
 AND approved='Yes'
```

A user is not going to friend himself.

*Side note: You should use prepared statements or at least escape the input from `$_GET` to prevent SQL injections.*